# StackOverflow Error while doing dualPivotQuickSort

Tags: java, sorting, runtime-error, stack-overflow, quicksort

I am using the dualPivotQuickSort algorithm which is linked below. Everything is fine until the array size has a 100.000 index. My program crashes and gives StackOverflow error when I  set the size 100.000 and put increasing or decreasing numbers in the array . There is no problem when random numbers used, even a 100.000 length array.
https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/24092/dual-pivot-quicksort-reference-implementation

```
    void sort(int[] A, int left, int right) {
    if (right > left) {
        // Choose outermost elements as pivots
        if (A[left] > A[right]) swap(A, left, right);
        int p = A[left], q = A[right];

        // Partition A according to invariant below
        int l = left + 1, g = right - 1, k = l;
        while (k <= g) {
            if (A[k] < p) {
                swap(A, k, l);
                ++l;
            } else if (A[k] >= q) {
                while (A[g] > q && k < g) --g;
                swap(A, k, g);
                --g;
                if (A[k] < p) {
                    swap(A, k, l);
                    ++l;
                }
            }
            ++k;
        }
        --l; ++g;

        // Swap pivots to final place
        swap(A, left, l); swap(A, right, g);

        // Recursively sort partitions
        sort(A, left, l - 1);
        sort(A, l + 1, g - 1);
        sort(A, g + 1, right);
    }
}

   void swap(int[] A, int i, int j) {
    final int tmp = A[i]; A[i] = A[j]; A[j] = tmp;
}
```

Comment: Debug your program. For stack overflow errors, the best way is to add a print statement to print the parameter values of every recursive method call. When the error occurs, the last few lines of that will show the pattern that caused too deep recursion. So add `System.out.println(left + "," + right);` right inside the method.

Comment: In this case, you'll likely find that there is simply too much data, and the limited size of the stack can't handle the number of recursions needed. This is why you generally never use the outermost elements as pivots.

Comment: Thx for your reply,  i will try your commands but still, I have a question about it . When I asked my friend to run that algorithm., it worked fine.What is wrong with my PC. :)

Comment: Don't know. Maybe different version of Java, so the default stack size is different?

Comment: Alright then, maybe I can try change of the stack size . As I know, the stack size is related to OS which you are using.

Comment: Increasing the stack size will just defer the problem. Sure, doubling the stack size might double the amount of data you can sort, but it is still limited. It would be better to fix the sorting algorithm so it won't need a linear amount of stack space.